# Are there any non-falling blocks that don't break boats?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In *Minecraft Bedrock Edition* (Nintendo Switch), boats can break apart if you ram them into most blocks. I know that sand is an exception to this rule; are there any others that aren't affected by gravity?

Comment: Are you talking about when boats would break into sticks and planks when you touched a block? Or are you talking about when it drops as an item?

Comment: When they break into sticks and planks.

Comment: When you are in the Main menu, what is the version number in the bottom right?

Comment: I don't really play Minecraft anymore. However, I still update the game, and I'd like the answer relevant to the newest version (1.20 I think)